# How to Reduce transfer time of big array through ajax

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

[image]**Description**

my code is transferring  json object from server to client using php,js trough ajax.  json object consist of big array (200X200) of integers.

server is localhost

**Problem**

Data transfer is getting delay so that it effect the js  web output, 
please let me know any points to tackle this problem.

[image]

Comment: Do you really need it all at once? I have a feeling the issue is not the ajax call, but you parsing it into an Array.

Comment: Is the trnasfer slow, or the generation of the array?

Comment: yes, since array contains changing result of background process

Comment: Do answer with `yes` to an `or` question?!

Comment: i think transfer is slow, generation part doesn't effect since i am testing with old generated data

Comment: How _slow_ is the transfer? Maybe add screenshots of you network tab.

Comment: Lets say 200x200 of 10 character integers; that's only 3,200,000 bits (400 kiloBytes) or 3 Megabits.  Should transfer over 10Mbps in less than .5 second with overhead.

Comment: i am getting over 2 s

Comment: at least  if i could reduce to 0.8 s  or around that , even using array optimization method, please let me know any possibility with that .

Comment: How the array is encoded and what is the actual amount of data being transferred? Perhaps you can reduce the size by using different encoding format?

Comment: @Eriks Klotins, Array  is around 4 MB in size ,can you please suggest any encoding method both python ( since array is generated by python script) and js (used by js) optimized

Answer (score 1):

If you have the ability to change the format in which the server expects the data, then you can try a more efficient format than JSON, such as raw binary data. In that case, you can shrink the payload to 200x200x4 bytes (or even less, depending on the range of values you want to send).